# What cause path error occurs during code compiling

Tags: compiling, make, arm, toolchain

Debian 32-bit host PC, with a pre-built toolchain in /opt dir, the target is ARM. I'm trying to build project (f/w image) from source code,there is error during code compilation. The project have complex structure with multiple automatically generated makefiles, that recursively located in subdirectories, that compose a whole system. I already fixed few errors that occurred during compilation,but every time new errors occur. 
Build stopped at some directory (pppd):

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1'
make -C pppd
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
/opt/emlix/pnx8181/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -pipe -Wall -g -DHAVE_PATHS_H -DIPX_CHANGE -DHAVE_MMAP -I../include '-DDESTDIR="/usr/local"' -DCHAPMS=1 -DMPPE=1 -DHAS_SHADOW -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DUSE_CRYPT=1 -DHAVE_MULTILINK -DUSE_TDB=1 -DPLUGIN -DMAXOCTETS -Wl,-E -o pppd main.o magic.o fsm.o lcp.o ipcp.o upap.o chap-new.o md5.o ccp.o ecp.o auth.o options.o demand.o utils.o sys-linux.o ipxcp.o tty.o eap.o chap-md5.o md4.o chap_ms.o sha1.o pppcrypt.o multilink.o tdb.o spinlock.o  -lcrypt -ldl
main.o:(.data+0x18): undefined reference to `cbcp_protent'
auth.o: In function `network_phase':
auth.c:(.text+0x28bc): undefined reference to `cbcp_protent'
multilink.o: In function `iterate_bundle_links':
/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd/multilink.c:364: undefined reference to `pppdb'
multilink.o: In function `remove_bundle_link':
/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd/multilink.c:352: undefined reference to `pppdb'
multilink.o: In function `make_bundle_links':
/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd/multilink.c:308: undefined reference to `pppdb'
multilink.o: In function `mp_join_bundle':
/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd/multilink.c:209: undefined reference to `pppdb'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:209: recipe for target 'pppd' failed
make[4]: *** [pppd] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
Makefile.cyt:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1'
/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_pppd' failed
make[2]: *** [_subdir_pppd] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source'
/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_open_source' failed
make[1]: *** [_subdir_open_source] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router'
Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_router' failed
make: *** [_subdir_router] Error 2
```

There is shown undefined reference so some file, but I'm sure there is no syntax errors in code, its may appear due to broken dependencies or paths.
I this place, this path path looks wrong to me: **-I../include '-DDESTDIR="/usr/local"'**

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/viltek/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
/opt/emlix/pnx8181/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -pipe -Wall -g -DHAVE_PATHS_H -DIPX_CHANGE -DHAVE_MMAP -I../include '-DDESTDIR="/usr/local"' -DCHAPMS=1 -DMPPE=1 -DHAS_SHADOW -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DUSE_CRYPT=1 -DHAVE_MULTILINK -DUSE_TDB=1 -DPLUGIN -DMAXOCTETS -Wl,-E -o pppd main.o magic.o fsm.o lcp.o ipcp.o upap.o chap-new.o md5.o ccp.o ecp.o auth.o options.o demand.o utils.o sys-linux.o ipxcp.o tty.o eap.o chap-md5.o md4.o chap_ms.o sha1.o pppcrypt.o multilink.o tdb.o spinlock.o  -lcrypt -ldl
```

I compared with make.log from a successful build, and it looks different:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/jlai2/project/payton_gpl/src/fullimage/payton/src/test/payton_1.3.2.009_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
/opt/emlix/pnx8181/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -pipe -Wall -D__linux__=1 -DHAVE_PATHS_H  -DHAVE_MMAP -I../include -I/home/jlai2/project/payton_gpl/src/fullimage/payton/src/test/payton_1.3.2.009_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/include  -DCHAPMS=1 -DMPPE=1 -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DUSE_CRYPT=1 -DPLUGIN -DCBCP_SUPPORT   -c -o main.o main.c
main.c: In function '_run_script':
main.c:1228: warning: unused variable 'i'
main.c:1227: warning: unused variable 'buf'
```

What cause the full path is not included after **-I../include**?

Comment: Can you provide more information on the firmware you are trying to compile? As you said, it looks like `pppd` is missing.

Comment: the `pppd` is not missing. What may cause the full path is not included after `-I../include`?

Comment: `I../include` and `'-DDESTDIR="/usr/local"'` are two separate things - and both are related to the compile phase (whereas `undefined reference to ...` errors are from the link phase). Why do you believe this is the source of your errors?